# UML диаграмма по уже написанному коду

Tags: c++, qt, проектирование, uml

Нужно составить uml диаграмму. Кода написано уже очень много.

ВОПРОС: есть ли средство, которое составить uml диаграмму с кода, чтобы не рисовать?

Проект написан на qt c++ в qt creator на windows

Comment: Средств таких очень много. Например, Rational Rose, однако она платная. Я лично пользуюсь бесплатным StarUML (http://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/) - он не такой навороченный как другие, но мои потребности покрывает. И уж UML диаграмму по коду (reverse engineering) составлять точно умеет)

Comment: из c++ реверсить диаграмму MS Visio точно умеет

Comment: @progzdeveloper StarUML только описал данный классов, а наследования, зависимости и т.д нужно вручную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одна из лучших программ используемых в индустрии MagicDraw (http://www.nomagic.com/products/magicdraw.html ). Она такое должна уметь делать. (Написанно в списке фичей http://www.nomagic.com/files/brochures/letter/MagicDrawDataSheet.pdf ). Насколько качественно - сказать не могу, да и QT, не факт, что получится адекватно воспринять.
То, что ты хочешь сделать называется Reverse Engineering